# when major version tells the JDK version what minor version tells?

Tags: java, jvm, java-ee-7, jvm-hotspot

When major version(45,46....51,52) tells the Java version then what minor version tells us ?

javap -verbose Test.class (Test is my user defined compiled class)

minor version: 0
 major version: 51

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/source_target_class_file_version